# Kotlin replace multiple words in string

Tags: kotlin

How to replace many parts of a string with something else in Kotlin using `.replace()`

For example, we can do it only by replacing one word

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var w_text = "welcome his name is John"

    println("${w_text.replace("his","here")}")
}
```

and the result will be " welcome here name is John " .

finally we need the result be " welcome here name is alles "

by replacing **his** to **here** and **john** to **alles** using  `.replace()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using multiple consecutive calls to `replace()`:

```
w_text.replace("his", "here").replace("john", "alles")
```

Comment: What about `s.replace("his", "JOHN").replace("JOHN", "Alles")` ?

Answer (score 10):

For the ones interested in replacing a map of values in a text:

```
private fun replaceText(text: String, keys: Map<String, String>): String =
    val replaced = map.entries.fold(text) { acc, (key, value) -> acc.replace(key, value) }
```

Answer (score 9):

You could write an extension that overloads `String::replace`:

```
fun String.replace(vararg replacements: Pair<String, String>): String {
    var result = this
    replacements.forEach { (l, r) -> result = result.replace(l, r) }
    return result
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val sentence = "welcome his name is John"
    sentence.replace("his" to "here", "John" to "alles")
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a one liner:

```
fun String.replace(vararg pairs: Pair<String, String>): String =
    pairs.fold(this) { acc, (old, new) -> acc.replace(old, new, ignoreCase = true) }
```

Test:

```
@Test fun rep() {

    val input = "welcome his name is John"

    val output = input.replace("his" to "her", "john" to "alles")

    println(output)

    output shouldBeEqualTo "welcome her name is alles"

}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have many of those replacement rules, then create a mapping of them and call the `replace` method in a loop:

```
val map = mapOf("his" to "here", "john" to "alles", ...)
val sentence = "welcome his name is John"
var result = sentence
map.forEach { t, u -> result = result.replace(t, u) }
println(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other responses but using Kotlin extension and overloading `String::replace` to accept a map of oldValue to newValue.

```kotlin
fun String.replace(mapping: Map<String, String>): String {
    var str = this
    mapping.forEach { str = str.replace(it.key, it.value) }
    return str
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val mapping = mapOf("his" to "here", "John" to "alles")
  
"his dad is John".replace(mapping)  // here dad is alles
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with just using replace without any regex is:
Let's say I want to replace the occurrence of "here" with "there" inside the string "Where is my bag? Your bag is here." As you can imagine the result will be "Wthere is my bag? Your bag is there." which will not be correct. The solution is to use a regex like given below.

```
    var str = "Where is my bag? Your bag is here."
    val replacements = setOf("\\bhere\\b" to "there",
        "\\bjohn\\b" to "alles")
    replacements.forEach {
        str = str.replace(Regex(it.first), it.second)
    }
```